# How to start matlabR2016a using command prompt when you have not set up any symbolic links?

Tags: command-line, matlab

I installed Matlab2016a on my Ubuntu 16.04. I did not set up symbolic links during the installation procedure. How can I run the software using command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out how to do it!!

type

```
matlabroot/bin/matlab
```

Where matlabroot is the name of the folder in which I installed MATLAB.